# Expect function Parameter to be Key of Object with Dynamic Properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im making an application multi Language.

I want to build typing as strict and simpel as possible. My Code is the following:

```
//=== Inside my Hook: ===//
interface ITranslation {
   [key:string]:[string, string]
}

const useTranslator = (translations:ITranslation) => {
   const language = useLanguage() // just getting the language setting from another hook

   const translate = (key:keyof typeof translations) => {
      // mapping and returning the right translation
   }

   return translate;
}


//=== Inside the component: ===//
const translation:ITranlation = {
   "something in english": [ "something in german", "something in spanish" ],
   "anotherthing in english": ["anotherthing in german", "anotherthing in spanish"]
}

const translate = useTranslation(translation)

return(
   <Text>{translate("something in english")}</Text>
)
```

What i want to achieve:

- When passing the `translation` Object, with Dynamic Keys to the Hook: `useTranslation(translations)`, there should be a typecheck validating, that both languages are provided (any property has an Array with 2 Strings)
- When using the translate function (inside the Text component) typescript should bring an error, if a key is not matching the Dynamic Keys inside the `translations` object. So this should throw an error: `tranlate("not a key in object")`

But i can't get it to work properly. I can either set the `translations` object `as const`, but then there is no typecheck when passing the object to the Hook.
Or i set it as shown above with `translation:ITranslation` but then there is no typechecking for the parameter in the ´translate´ function inside the component.

Is it possible to achive that? (If yes, how?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of ts are you using?

Comment: @wonderflame  typescript: 4.9.4

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2909W) work for you then? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: This works like a charm. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work only for Typescript `>= 4.9` since it uses the [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) introduced in the `4.9`.

Adding `as const` is the approach we will go with, and `satisfies` will allow us to type-check it.

```
const translation = {
  'something in english': ['something in german', 'something in spanish'],
  'anotherthing in english': ['anotherthing in german', 'anotherthing in spanish'],
} as const satisfies ITranslation;
```

Since we added `as const` the values in the `ITranslation` will be `readonly [string, string]`, thus we have to update the `ITranslation` to the following:

```
interface ITranslation {
  [key: string]: readonly [string, string];
}
```

Next, we need to add a generic parameter to `useTranslator` so it works over the specific instance of `ITranslation`.  The same goes for the `translate` function. It should accept the generic parameter for the key of `ITranslation` and return the value for that specific key:

```
const useTranslator = <T extends ITranslation>(translations: T) => {
  const language = useLanguage(); // just getting the language setting from another hook

  const translate = <K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K][number] => {
    // return retrieved value
  };

  return translate;
};
```

Since it is not asked in the question `translate` will return a union of the translations for the specific key, which is achieved by `T[K][number]`

Usage:

```
const Component = () => {
  const translate = useTranslator(translation);
  
  // "something in german" | "something in spanish"
  const case1 = translate('something in english');

  // "anotherthing in german" | "anotherthing in spanish"
  const case2 = translate( 'anotherthing in english');

  return null;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUpxAZwDZxjAD2IyA3gLABQyyA2gNYQCeAXMjmFKAOYC6HKBDgATUnhYMuPELwA0nbn34BuGgF8aNBKS7IArjggAZbLwNxeKALzIAFAEpkNgHwUadYWANQyAcggQf3VqDVCdPTBDY0xsfEJiKBdkAB50ZAgAD0gQURw0ONwCIlJXe254kpJcDnRnNw9aZF1caII5S2sUo1NzLognVWQAehHkACsjaOswIjlkMAALFA6LKxRjOb5kGChiAFtkbGJl6GQl4mJGbWbW-Uriwls0gGlMnKD85GYWYhhkOhyr8OK9HHV6K9+PQQAYDgAjaD8FzuKjNLwQHx+CgaY4FbAsUJ0cK3DFYsiPBKQUIk6g0MY2RloXDAUQoM4tQ4AB1IQTAHEZNjGkTaiywT1KZDsaLo-hwh0xSx2oEycjwwBwS38HHocoVy2VZGsUAO2H8ij1B0Vhs4XOwGq1-HknmQ-hOZygBoWKqCvHVmu1DDdIFOK09Su9RugpuCFvdYa9vGQKpwdpADv8Ts0eM5opwhA1MGAEAKGHFVJqEWo92iAGFubzwCknCimnQa2Kqs8erFyyUkhU+wXSI4q+2oi04MYAIwpSklQaW62R1V+jOjl1jOh0AB6AH5Sbn9AgpxAAExzoeQeyu+PQRPJsi+-1ajfNLfb-eH7y+MiwvB4DSoRAA)

Comment: in my case its working without the `satisfies`. But maybe im missing something right now,

Comment: We need satisfies fo make the type-checking on the `translation`